# Docker base image state replication

Tags: docker

I have a DockerFile that builds from an Ubuntu base image. I also have the following command that instructs my container to do an update:

```
RUN apt-get update
```

If I run my container at different points in time, I cannot guarantee that my Ubuntu base image and the respective packages that gets updated each time with the apt-get update command to be the same. How can I guarantee that it always remains the same?

Comment: Your container images will only change when you *build* them, or commit changes.  Can you clarify if you want things to change every day (to pick up security fixes, say) or to remain the same over long periods (to avoid unexpected incompatibilities, say)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run RUN apt-get update in a base image of your own and then publish/deploy that to dockerhub with a known tag, e.g. date of build. Then in your subsequent images you can say something like the line below. This way you will never have dependencies update out from under you even if you are making a lot of changes to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM me/ubuntu:18_11_2014
```

Comment: Should `with` be `from` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to note that images will only be updated if you run `docker build`, not by `docker run`. Even then, Docker caches layers by default and the `apt-get update` line will only be re-run if something above it changes or you explicitly turn off caching.

It's almost impossible to ensure that your builds produce exactly the same image all the time, which is a known issue. Your best bet is to pass a version number to apt-get e.g. `apt-get install -y nautilus=2.2.4-1`, which should be good enough for you. However, remember that any dependencies pulled in by the installed software may have changed (dependencies are often specified as >= a specific version), which will mean the image is still likely to change. Also, remember at some point old packages will simply be removed from the Debian repos.

Answer (score 0):

That command is executed only when you build the image.
If you want to run a command each time a container is started, you should consider to use the `CMD` statement instead of the `RUN` one.